# странности с jar играми

Tags: java, jar, main

Cкачал для изучения работы игр одну игру, файл с расширением .jar.
извлек данные в отдельную папку, декомпилировал файлы .class. там не нашел класс, где есть  public static void main(String[] args){}.

Как мне запустить такую игру?  вот ссылка на этот .jar 
https://dropmefiles.com/HhXIt

Comment: поищите метод startApp()

Answer (score 1):

> Как мне запустить такую игру? вот ссылка на этот .jar https://dropmefiles.com/HhXIt

Запустить можно из terminal, но там в игре ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, а двойным щелчком можно бы запустить при установленном Java Runtime Environment (JRE) и конфигурировании Properties файла на открытие java - указать путь к исполняемому файлу, что-то вроде c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe или javaw.exe

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/QDd4h  мдаа уж..  пробовал не через терминал а с помощью такого подхода  - https://dropmefiles.com/LgBJc , интересно что означает no main manifest attribute? имеется ввиду, что нет класса содержащий метод main? или это другой main?  данная неоднозначность понимания этого выражения основан на инфо по этой ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776505/creating-jar-with-intellij-2016-no-main-manifest-attribute

Comment: нашел это, вроде manifest но все равно проблема непонятна https://dropmefiles.com/SHS0b

Comment: Вы спрашивали, как запустить - нормальные jar так запускаются, поэтому ответ на Ваш вопрос дан. А ошибки в самой игре - другая тема)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не меняйте суть вопроса. снова напишу вопрос "Как мне запустить ТАКУЮ игру...?"  а не "как вообще запускают игры...". Надеюсь на понимание. Добавлю что это не первая игра такая, уже которую скачиваю и один и тот же результат. запуска нет.